# What is the best way to send Bulk email with Mandrill

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mandrill

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application where I need to send an HTML newsletter for about 80000 emails. I installed [Mandrill-dotnet](https://github.com/shawnmclean/Mandrill-dotnet) and I have a few questions:

1. How would you send so many emails? Through the API correct?
   Would you add the emails to the TO List? How many by send?
2. How do you take care of the failed sending? My idea would be:

   ```
   Queue<String> emails = new Queue<String>();
      for each block of 200 emails {
        try {
          send
          remove the 200 emails from queue
        } catch (Exception) {
          log exception
      }   
   }
   ```

   Well, I am not sure the best way to do this?
3. Can you do this on an MVC action?
   I suppose I can't because the thread cannot be alive for so much time or am I wrong?
   How should I do this?

I appreciate if someone could advice me on out to do this.

Comment: Another option : https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

Comment: That faciliates the creation of the emails but does not solve the problem of sensing thousands of emails ...

Comment: **Stop signing your posts**. You've been a user here for **three years**. You must know by now that you're not supposed to do that.

Answer (score -1):

From Mandrill's [help](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/27045476-Can-I-upload-my-list-in-Mandrill-):

> Lists cannot be uploaded or stored in Mandrill. Recipient or subscriber lists should be managed in your own database or application. Then, when you're reading to send an email, recipient information is passed to Mandrill in your API request or SMTP message.
>
> Note: If you're looking for a service that provides list-management services as well as the ability to create and track bulk emails, check out [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/).

You really should be using MailChimp for this, Mandrill is meant for *transactional* e-mail, not bulk e-mail.

Comment: I am not looking to manage email lists. I already have an application that does that ... I am just looking for a gateway to send the emails ... But I need to send Bulk emails.

Comment: I still think you're using the wrong tool for the job. Mandrill is not suited to your purpose. Mailgun from Rackspace probably fits better: http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#batch-sending

Comment: I disagree that Mandrill isn't right. There are many transactional emails that might need to be sent in bulk - renewal reminders for example. I have the requirement listed above - did you solve this?

Comment: renewal reminders would be a dynamic list of recipients. how would you send this in bulk? bcc?

Comment: datashaman his use case is simple. Imaging a high volume app with tens of signups per second. Such an app might have a queue of unsent transactional emails that build up then gets sent in batches via a bulk send endpoint. Postmark offers a transactional service like this. @niico  I also have a bulk library built in ruby that you could translate to whatever you like.

Comment: There remains an INSANE price difference between transactional and 'bulk' pricing (Mandrill vs. Mailchimp) when you rarely send marketing emails. Pricing for Mailchimp / Constant Contact is based on frequent sending to the same customers. To send 100,000 emails on Mandrill costs $80. To send ZERO or ONE or TWELVE emails to 100,000 loaded contacts on MailChimp costs $800.

Comment: However their terms do clearly say: "Prohibited: Send bulk emails, meaning emails directed to a number of individuals with the same content, through Transactional (formerly known as Mandrill). Transactional is designed for transactional email. Please use Mailchimp campaigns for your bulk sending needs."

Comment: _cough_ i believe my answer is valid...